# edit video in async python

Tags: python, asynchronous

i would like to edit several videos in python in parallel with moviepy

```
async def upload():
    edit_tasks = [edit(path, video_random, video) for video in videos]
    path_finals = await asyncio.gather(*edit_tasks)

async  def edit(path,random_video,video) : 
    video1_path = video
    video2_path = random_video
    video2 = video2.resize(width=video1.size[0])
    combine = clips_array([[video1],[video2]])
    x_center = (combine.w - 720) // 2
    y_center = (combine.h - 1280) // 2
    final_cropped = combine.crop(x_center, y_center, x_center + 720, y_center + 1280)
    semi_final_video_name = chemin_semi_final+"\\"+video_name
    final_cropped.write_videofile(semi_final_video_name,codec="libx264", audio_codec="aac")
```

Comment: Is async important for you, or can it be any parallel processing (e.g. `import multiprocessing`)? If async is not important, then replace it with parallel in the question title.

Comment: Why is parallel processing important for you? Is possible faster completion the only reason?

Comment: Have you measured how much faster your program becomes if you run 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 and 8 parallel copies of it (for the same video file)? Maybe it won't become much faster, because moviepy already uses all your available CPU power even with a single copy.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.